# Tkinter scrollbars not filling or aligning correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a frame with both a vertical and horizontal scrollbar, but the horizontal one seems to pack next to the canvas, and not below it. I have the scrollbar packed with `side=tk.BOTTOM` and `fill=tk.X`, so I'm not sure what else I need to add. What should I do to get the horizontal scrollbar to stretch across the entire canvas?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()

frame=tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

canvas=tk.Canvas(frame, height=200, width=200, background="blue")
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

yscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
yscrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

xscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
xscrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Right now the `canvas` is set to `side=tk.LEFT`. If I set it to `side=tk.TOP`, the reverse problem happens.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from the order in which you pack the widgets. The idea is that pack uses the remaining space to put what is left, so you need to pack first the scrollbars, then at last the canvas:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()

frame=tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

canvas=tk.Canvas(frame, height=200, width=200, background="blue")

yscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)


xscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)

xscrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
yscrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: scrennshot]

However, because `pack` is not so intuitive when it comes to more complex GUI, I prefer to use `grid`:

```
xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ewns')
```

But in this case, if you want your GUI to resize properly,  you will need to add

```
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

so that the row and column 0 of the grid will fill all the available space.

Comment: Thank you — could have sworn I tested the `pack`ing order, but I guess not!

Answer (score 0):

In my env, calling canvas.pack and frame.pack after defining y and xscrollbar worked fine.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()

frame=tk.Frame(root)

yscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
yscrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

xscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
xscrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

canvas=tk.Canvas(frame, height=200, width=200, background="blue")
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

frame.pack()

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)

root.mainloop()
```